# Not able to appendChild in HTML5 Drag & drop,No jquery please

Tags: javascript, html

I have two columns & I want to drag & drop div between these columns.
I making this drag function work using the following

```
var _dragStart =function(event){
        console.log("Method Executing:dragDrop.dragStart")
        var x=event.dataTransfer.setData('draggable',event.target);
    }
```

Here event.target is an html div element having children.
Where as for dropping

```
var _dropOver = function(event){
        console.log("Method Executing:dragDrop.dropOver");
        event.preventDefault();
        var getTask = event.dataTransfer.getData('draggable');
        event.target.appendChild(getTask);
        }
```

But it is throwing an error as

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this error because getTask is a `String`, not a `Node`. You can see that `event.dataTransfer.getData` returns a `String` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer#getData.28.29

`appendChild` takes a `Node`, not a `String`. That's why you're not able to get it to work.

Comment: Thanks! but is there any alternative way to do it?

Comment: You're welcome! And I'm sorry, but I don't have experience with drag and drop so I'm not sure how you would do it.